# Why does Sqlite3 gets installed in /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin, while compiling and installing from source?

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

I downloaded the tar - sqlite-autoconf-3130000.tar.gz and proceeded to:

./configure and make install.

sqlite3 gets installed into /usr/local/bin, instead of /usr/bin .

When I try to see the result of installation by - sqlite3 --version, it says no such file or directory in /usr/bin.

Later on I find that it has been installed in /usr/local/bin.

Why does it happen so?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SQLite itself.

Everything managed by your distribution is supposed to go into `/usr`, while stuff that you've added manually is supposed to go into `/usr/local`. (This makes your additions independent from any distribution updates.)

Therefore, the compilation scripts of most software use `/usr/local` as the default prefix, and your distribution would call somthing like `./configure --prefix=/usr` to generate its own package.